# disable all controls in the page using jquery

Tags: jquery

How to disable all the controls(buttons, anchor, textbox,...) in the page using jquery. I need this to show a preview of a page, in which i don't want to the user to click anything.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$("#id_button").attr("disabled","disabled");
```

or

```
$(".class_buttons").attr("disabled","disabled");
```

or

```
$(":input").attr("disabled","disabled");
```

Comment: That last selector is awesome, I didn't realize that it selections all inputs- textarea, select, textbox etc.

Answer (score 0):

This may work:

```
$(document).click(function(evt){ evt.preventDefault; });
```

Answer (score -1):

The best way will be to show a div on top of all other elements. Make the stacking order of this div to be the highest in the document so that click won't be made on any other elements.

[Specifying the stack level: the 'z-index' property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#z-index)

Comment: If you need to make a modal popup then I think this is the right way to do it.