# Onclick Disable Other Hyperlinks

Tags: javascript, html

I have a django template where i render a list contaning objects that would form a hyperlink
like

```
{% for o in list_o %}
  <a href="{% url tolink o.lan,o.id %}">{% o.name %}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

I would like to disable or blur the other links when a user click on one of the formed link.

Comment: take a look at this answer it should give you what you want.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788210/disable-all-controls-in-the-page-using-jquery

Comment: This is not a django question. Is a js question

Comment: Is this so you can make sure that the user doesn't click anywhere else (and the original link is allowed to load)? That is, is the disabling effect only required until the next page loads?

Comment: Yes this is to not allow the user to click on any other links once he has clicked on one link and should be there even after the next page loads..

Comment: Ah - OK, that's trickier. Whatever you do in the original page with JS will not be present on the next page. You're going to need to reconstruct the list with the enabled/disabled states on the next page, either on the server (better), or on the client with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
function handleLinks(linkIDList, disable) {
    if (disable) {
        $(linkIDList).attr("disabled","true");
    } else {
         $(linkIDList).removeAttr("disabled");
    }
}
```

Assuming all your link tags will have ID's use this function i created.

Add the onclick="handleLinks('#link1,#link2',true)" to your link.

The function takes a list of ids in jQuery format "#id,#id2,#id3", and boolean true to disable false to enable.

If your not using jQuery just say and ill provide an allterive solution!

Comment: The disabled attribute is not valid on anchor elements and shouldn't be relied on (though it does kinda work in IE). Instead, you should capture clicks and prevent the default behaviour from occurring.

Comment: Thanks for this but i am not supposed to use jquery here